# Socket sync send outperform async beginsend/endsend?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, asynchronous

I am writing the tcp server that supports a lot of(50,000+) connection, and I found out about this.

The sync send performed at least 3 times better than the async one. The programs are identical besides these two lines:

```
m_socket.Send(sendingBuffer, length, SocketFlags.None);
```

and

```
m_socket.BeginSend(sendingBuffer, 0, length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), this);
```

In SendCallback I just call EndSend, nothing else.

Where is this huge performance difference coming from?  Aren't async methods supposed to perform better?

Comment: Have you tried the SendAsync API? That can actually be sync or async (the return value tells you which it used). The SendAsync API is what I use for our websockets server here, which handles similar traffic.

Comment: 3x faster doing what? How much data are you transferring? It beggars belief that both wouldn't ultimately be network-bound rather than CPU-bound.

Comment: Doing sending.  It's a very simple relay server forwarding requests to connected peers.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I will try SocketAsyncEventArgs next.  That requires an overhaul of the whole server.  I will post the result later.

Answer (score 3):

Async methods are usually **slower** then sync methods (due to involving some added overhead in implementation), but are overall "faster" if you need to do something **while** they are executing - if you are just waiting for them to finish, they are completely unnecessary.

Comment: That's what I figure.  If I can guarantee the send buffer is not full, and my send won't be blocked by the tcp send window, then sync send is a better choice.

Comment: Async being slower by itself is a key point that is being missed a lot! I can confirm this observation from my own benchmarking.